# Multiplying individual digits in a number with each other in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to make a program that will take the digits in a number and multiply them with each other. So `583` would be `5*8*3 = 120`.

Its not working as intended, its just returning the `number` that was put in.

How can I fix it?

Here's the code:

```js
function persistence(num) {
  //code me
  numString = num.toString();
  numArray = numString.split().map(function(t) {
    return parseInt(t)
  });


  function reducer(theNumArray) {
    let sum = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < theNumArray.length; i++) {
      sum = sum * theNumArray[i];

    }
    return sum;
  }
  newNum = reducer(numArray);

  console.log(newNum);
};

persistence(485);
```

Comment: `"485".split() === [ "485" ]`

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 6):

You could split the string with an empty string, for getting single digits. Then covert, if required all strings to a number.

```js
function reducer(theNumArray) {
    var i, sum = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < theNumArray.length; i++) {
        sum *= theNumArray[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

function persistence(num) {
    var numArray = num.toString().split('').map(Number);
    return reducer(numArray);
}

console.log(persistence(485));
```

A shorter approach could be just taking the single digits by using a spread syntax with an iterator for strings, then just multiply the values and return the result.

```js
function persistence(number) {
    return [...number.toString()].reduce((p, v) => p * v);
}

console.log(persistence(485));
```

Comment: really clean solution with reduce.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change inside `split('')`

**DEMO**

```js
function persistence(num) {
  //code me
  numString = num.toString();
  numArray = numString.split('').map(function(t) {
    return parseInt(t)
  });

  function reducer(theNumArray) {
    let sum = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < theNumArray.length; i++) {
      sum = sum * theNumArray[i];

    }
    return sum;
  }
  newNum = reducer(numArray);

  console.log(newNum);
};

persistence(485);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You can also use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method for array.

> ES5

```js
function persistence(num) {
  let result = num.toString().split('').reduce(function(total, v) {
    return total * v
  }, 1);
  console.log(result);
};

persistence(485);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

> ES6

It Can be more easy with [`Spread_syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) of ES6.

```js
function persistence(num) {
  let result = [...num.toString()].reduce((total, v) => total * v, 1);
  console.log(result);
};

persistence(485);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to split the string you can just reference the chars by their number. This seems to work fine example for 4*8*5= 160.

> The other way (introduced in ECMAScript 5) is to treat the string as
>   an array-like object, where individual characters correspond to a
>   numerical index

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

```js
function persistence(num) {
  numString = num.toString();
  let sum = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < numString.length; i++) {
    sum = sum * numString[i];
  }
  console.log(sum);
};
persistence(485);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming num is a positive integer:

```
    function persistence(num) {
    var ans=1;    
    while( num!==0){
            ans=ans*(num-Math.floor(num/10)*10);
            num=Math.floor(num/10);

        }
        console.log(ans);
    }

    persistence(123);
```

This is based on (num-Math.floor(num/10)*10) extracting the least significant digit. For example

123 - Math.floor(123/10)*10

123 - 12*10

123 - 120

3

And so on after reducing num by one digits by integer divide by 10. 
You don't need strings.

Comment: `num-Math.floor(num/10)*10` could be just `num % 10`

Answer (score 1):

according to [this](http://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/strings/split.php) the split method will have different results based on the inputs (obvious right?):

No Separator-> If you don't pass a separator argument to the split method, the resulting array will have a single element consisting of the entire string

so, basically from here:

`numString.split()`

you will get an array with the string (your number) inside of it, this should be changed to:

`numString.split('')`

so your whole code should be like this:

```
 function persistence(num) {
    numString = num.toString();
    numArray = numString.split().map(function(t) {
       return parseInt(t)
    });


 function reducer(theNumArray) {
     let sum = 1;
     for (var i = 0; i < theNumArray.length; i++) {
         sum = sum * theNumArray[i];
     }
     return sum;
 }
 newNum = reducer(numArray);

 console.log(newNum);
};

persistence(485);
```